# How can I get photos to save to S3 with Heroku and Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

So On my localhost when I upload photos and check the url, they are saved to s3.  When I do the same on heroku, the files are saved locally to the app.  here are my heroku env vars:

```
=== boundarystaging Config Vars
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:           xxxxxxxxxxx
AWS_BUCKET_NAME:             xxxxxxxxx.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DATABASE_URL:                postgres://ukbcnhkvbcznkw:s9ENAi7XVUeV-   LiMv4FiC2CT6n@ec2-54-243-178-223.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d89nireva8vtl3
GEM_PATH:                    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_IVORY_URL: postgres://ukbcnhkvbcznkw:s9ENAi7XVUeV-   LiMv4FiC2CT6n@ec2-54-243-178-223.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d89nireva8vtl3
HEROKU_URL:                  http://boundarystaging.herokuapp.com
HUBOT_CAMPFIRE_TOKEN:        4d1caffdecf1ba19168cdb27eb75673ddf4979c3
LANG:                        en_US.UTF-8
RACK_ENV:                    staging
RAILS_ENV:                   staging
S3_BUCKET_NAME:              xxxxxxxxx.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

I x'd out all my keys, obviously. I'm just not seeing why the photos wouldn't be saving to s3 on my staging server.  for comparison, here are my prod vars:

```
=== boundaryprod Config Vars
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AWS_BUCKET:                  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.s3-website-us-west- 2.amazonaws.com
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DATABASE_URL:                  postgres://pwwxmdmnvciedi:D9td9clWzUObF3lW4ajNJVK30F@ec2-54-227-238-25.compute-   1.amazonaws.com:5432/d73ap5ocubncpl
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_IVORY_URL:   postgres://pwwxmdmnvciedi:D9td9clWzUObF3lW4ajNJVK30F@ec2-54-227-238-25.compute-  1.amazonaws.com:5432/d73ap5ocubncpl
```

The photos save fine on the prod app. both are on Heroku.  Any ideas?